# Python: Need help, for loop print not working properly

Tags: python

I was wondering why the `print("YES")` and `print("NO")` is not in the for loop. This program is to loop if the permutation of a string is a palindrome x amount of times. If yes it prints "YES" and if no it prints "NO".

```
number = int(input())
for i in range(number):
string = input()


found = False
char_set = set(string)

d_dict = {}
for c in char_set:
    d_dict[c] = string.count(c)

odd_l = [e for e in d_dict.values() if e%2 == 1]
if len(odd_l) >1:
    pass
else:
    found = True


if not found:
    print("NO")

else:
    print("YES")
```

Comment: Why do you think the prints should be in the loop?

Comment: I'm confused: first, this program does not seem to check whether the string is a palindrome (perhaps what you mean is whether it would be possible for some permutation of the string to be a palindrome?). Second, why are you wondering why the print statements are not in the loop?

Comment: I'm new to python. I literally just started today.

Comment: And yes, I am trying to find wether some permutation of the string could be a palindrome (As stated in the comment above). Basically, this should be my input                                                                                                                first line: 3                                                                                                                            second line: ccaabcbb   third line: azzza                                            fourth line: bbbbccccdddddddd                                                                     output:

Comment: Output should be: NO YES YES                                                                   
 all in different lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are wondering why print statements is not in the for loop,
I guess you did not write the code yourself.
If your code is from an online tutorial,
then I suggest switch to another one.

```
for i in range(number):
string = input()
```

This does not work. Python is layout sensitive.

```
for i in range(number):
  string = input()
```

This is valid Python code. But the semantic may be wrong. See below.

```
if not found:
    print("NO")

else:
    print("YES")
```

For your question, it is obvious to me the print statements should not in the for loop.

However, if I find difficult in understanding a long block of code,
I usually try to refactor it into small functions:

```
def get_inputs():
  number = int(input())
  for i in range(number):
    string = input()
  return number, string

def is_palindrome(number, string):
  found = False
  char_set = set(string)

  d_dict = {}
  for c in char_set:
    d_dict[c] = string.count(c)

  odd_l = [e for e in d_dict.values() if e%2 == 1]
  if len(odd_l) >1:
    pass
  else:
    found = True

  return found

def report(found):
  if not found:
    print("NO")
  else:
    print("YES")

def main():
  number, string = get_inputs()
  result = is_palindrome(number, string)
  report(result)

main()
```

I hope this version is clearer on why print statements is not in the loop,
and why `for i in range(number): string = input()` is wrong.

P.S. I thought you mean why print is not in the second loop,
but it turns out you mean why print is not in the first loop:

> Output should be: NO YES YES all in different lines

Yes, you are right. The code is wrongly indented.

```
number = int(input())
for i in range(number):
    string = input()

    # the algorithm does the work

    if not found:
        print("NO")

    else:
        print("YES")
```

Once we found the problem, try to fix it.

First, go back to spec:

given a number and some strings, report results on those strings.

Then `get_inputs` should not return an `int` and a `str`,
but an `int` and a list of strings `List[str]`.
How Python represent the concept of `and`?
Some languages use multiple return values,
Python dose not.
Instead, Python still return one value, but this value is a tuple containing two values.

```
return (first_result, second_result)
```

And Python allows you to omit the parentheses:

```
return first_result, second_result
```

Change `get_inputs` as:

```
def get_inputs():
  # do not need to touch this line
  number = int(input())
  # change string to strings
  strings = [input() for i in range(number)]
  # change return value accordingly
  return number, strings
```

Here `[input() for i in range(number)]` means
building a list based on `range(number)`,
for every element in `range(number)`,
fill the result of `input()` in the list to build.
It is sometimes clearer than a for loop.

And actually `number` is not used in `is_palindrome`,
just remove it

```
def is_palindrome(string):
    # function body dose not need to change
```

Then change the `main` function:

```
def main():
  # change string to strings accordingly
  number, strings = get_inputs()
  # change result to result in a way similar to
  # the change of `string -> strings` in `get_inputs()`.
  results = [is_palindrome(string) for string in strings]
  for result in results:
      report(result)
  # We could write [report(result) for result in results] here.
  # But we are not interested in the result list
  # The result list will be [None, None, ...].
  # So this is side-effects only.
  # A for loop is usually preferred for side-effects only,
  # and list comprehension for building a list.
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Timothy/PycharmProjects/PythonTesting/Cool.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Timothy/PycharmProjects/PythonTesting/Cool.py", line 32, in main
    report(result)
NameError: name 'report' is not defined

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake in indentation. `report` is wrongly indented, becoming a nested function inside `is_palindrome`. Fixed now.

Comment: For some reason, it still only outputs 1 answer. And that answer is "YES"

Comment: Yes. The semantics of my refactored version is user given a input and some  strings, __discard__ all those strings except the last one, and report the result on last one. Thus why I said "is clearer ... why for i in range(number): string = input() is wrong". So it is not a working version, it tries to reveal problems in the original code. Change two lines of `get_inputs()` so the semantic will be correct but not intended: given a number and a string, report the result.

Comment: Alternatively, change `get_inputs` to return a tuple of `int, List[str]`, and change `main` to apply `is_palindrome` and `report` on that `List[str]` (via for loop or list comprehension) will give the intended semantics: report results for an `int` and some strings.

Comment: I'm so confused but

Comment: +1 anyway. I really appreciate your help, but I'm new to Python so i don't really understand what you're saying;D

Comment: @Kuais My fault. My comments are not clear.  I took so many concepts for granted.  I added a working version to the answer with comments on how to get a working version from a not working version. Learning new languages may be frustrating. My suggests is refactor code into small functions, change variable name to long ones (to express what it is used for), and write out input parameter and return types in comments. I found this helps to understand and fix code. You can try this approach yourself. And powerful IDEs may detect a lot of problems automatically (I recommend PyCharm).

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
for i in range(number):
string = input()
```

doesn't work due to the `for i in range(number):` having a colon at the end, implying further expansion on what the program is going to do with each iteration through the range of the variable 'number'. The corrected code should look like either this:

```
for i in range(number): string = input()
```

or better organised:

```
for i in range(number):
    string = input()
```

and then embed anything else you want in the for loop by 4 characters after that.